# How important is it to have unique descriptions on Google Maps for the same business for multiple locations?

Tags: google-maps

A company operates in 6 different cities, each with its own unique address and phone number. This company offers the same service in each city. We have a Google My Business page for each of the cities.

How important is it to have a unique description on each Google page?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I called Google Support and they said that it does not hurt if we have the same exact description for multiple Google My Business pages for the same business at different locations (assuming they offer the same service).

It is recommend to have unique descriptions, especially if each location stands out in some way, but from an SEO perspective, it makes no difference.

Thank you.